# How do I run multiple linear models for unique IDs and put the results in a single dataframe by the unique IDs?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How do I get the regression intercept and coefficient data for unique IDs in a dataframe into a single dataframe where each row has the UID, it's intercept, and it's coefficients?

This is a snippet of what my raw data looks like. Future data can have more UIDs and more fields (independent variables).

| UID | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 | Rating |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.377489423 | 0.950311846 | 0.892135293 | 0.077054085 | 4 |
| 1 | 0.595570737 | 0.824334482 | 0.388634543 | 0.947936483 | 4 |
| 1 | 0.585703124 | 0.825486315 | 0.569809886 | 0.321117521 | 3 |
| 1 | 0.386968371 | 0.594556911 | 0.260187376 | 0.394238102 | 4 |
| 1 | 0.532731866 | 0.219741858 | 0.865710517 | 0.173044631 | 3 |
| 1 | 0.16565561 | 0.125096015 | 0.881841651 | 0.494690133 | 4 |
| 2 | 0.42418965 | 0.814894214 | 0.989426645 | 0.871014023 | 1 |
| 2 | 0.742604257 | 0.571780036 | 0.247811255 | 0.468820653 | 2 |
| 2 | 0.401989919 | 0.375134173 | 0.539599593 | 0.443260146 | 3 |
| 2 | 0.167910365 | 0.940073739 | 0.490081723 | 0.803074574 | 5 |
| 2 | 0.614160221 | 0.045817359 | 0.077645469 | 0.367456074 | 4 |
| 3 | 0.866397055 | 0.2932472 | 0.968410252 | 0.348542304 | 5 |
| 3 | 0.141680391 | 0.998446121 | 0.201506356 | 0.689863785 | 1 |
| 3 | 0.407182414 | 0.721650663 | 0.174277013 | 0.922810374 | 1 |

Here is the code I wrote to loop through each unique UID and run the linear model and add the intercept and coefficients for each UID to a list.

```
ids = df.UID.unique()

op=[]
for i in ids:
    df_i = df[df.UID == i]
    X =df_i.drop(['UID','Rating'], axis=1)
    y= df_i['Rating']
    reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
    reg.score(X, y)
    const = reg.intercept_
    coef = reg.coef_
    op.append(const)
    op.append(coef)
op
```

I would like my output to look like this format (the data shown is dummy data). So each row has the UID, it's intercept, and the linear regression coefficients. This is where I am stuck.

| UID | Intercept | A1 | A2 | A3 | A4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3.2343 | 0.950311846 | 0.892135293 | 0.077054085 | 4.3454 |
| 2 | 2.123 | 0.824334482 | 0.388634543 | 0.947936483 | 2.3454 |
| 3 | 3.455 | 0.825486315 | 0.569809886 | 0.321117521 | 3.12343 |

Feel free to comment on the initial approach to get the regression models as well.

Thank you

Comment: Can you please explain the logic to get the result?

Comment: @MayankPorwal Sure. My data is for many people each with their own unique ID (UID). I would like to run a linear regression for each person. The data doesn't always have the same number of independent variables but the dependent variable name will always be the same so I will always have a UID field and a Rating field.  I would like my output to be the intercept and coefficients for each of the independent variables for each UID.

Answer (score 0):

See changes below:

```
ids = df.UID.unique()

op=pd.DataFrame()

for i in ids:
    
    df_i = df[df.UID == i]
    X =df_i.drop(['UID','Rating'], axis=1)
    y= df_i['Rating']
    reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
    reg.score(X, y)
    const = reg.intercept_
    coef = reg.coef_
    uid=i
    array=np.append(coef,const)
    array=np.append(array,uid)
    array=array.reshape(1,len(array))
    df_append=pd.DataFrame(array)
    op=op.append(df_append)

op.columns=['A'+str(i) for i in range (1,len(op.columns)+1)]
op.rename(columns={op.columns[-1]:"UID"},inplace=True)
op.rename(columns={op.columns[-2]:"Intercept"},inplace=True)
op=op.reset_index().drop('index',axis=1)
op=op.drop_duplicates()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up with/. I just need to add the UID, not sure how to add that for each row.

```
ids = df.UID.unique()

op = pd.DataFrame
intercept = []
coefficients=[]
UID = []
for i in ids:
    df_i = df[df.UID == i]
    X =df_i.drop(['UID','Rating'], axis=1)
    y= df_i['Rating']
    reg = LinearRegression().fit(X, y)
    reg.score(X, y)
    unique_id=df_i['UID'].unique()   
    const = reg.intercept_
    coef = reg.coef_
    UID.append(unique_id)
    intercept.append(const)
    coefficients.append(coef)

intercep_new = pd.DataFrame(intercept)
coefficients_new = pd.DataFrame(coefficients)
UID_new = pd.DataFrame(UID)

colNames = df.drop(['Rating',], axis=1).columns
colNames = colNames.insert(1, 'Const')
colNames

op = pd.concat([UID_new,intercep_new, coefficients_new], axis=1)
op.columns = colNames
```